# How to insert a column in a julia DataFrame at specific position (without referring to existing column names)

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a DataFrame in Julia with hundreds of columns, and I would like to insert a column after the first one.

For example in this DataFrame:

```
df = DataFrame(
  colour = ["green","blue"],
  shape = ["circle", "triangle"],
  border = ["dotted", "line"]
)
```

I would like to insert a column `area` after `colour`, but without referring specifically to `shape` and `border` (that in my real case are hundreds of different columns).

```
df[:area] = [1,2]
```

In this example I can use (but referring specifically to `shape` and `border`):

```
df = df[[:colour, :area, :shape, :border]] # with specific reference to shape and border names
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Update: This function has changed. See @DiegoJavierZea ’s comment.

Well, congratulate you found a workaround your self, but there is a built-in function that is semantically more clear and possibly a little bit faster:

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(
  colour = ["green","blue"],
  shape = ["circle", "triangle"],
  border = ["dotted", "line"]
)

insert!(df, 3, [1,2], :area)
```

Where `3` is the expected index for the new column after the insertion, `[1,2]` is its content, and `:area` is the name. You can find a more detailed document by typing `?insert!` in REPL after loading the `DataFrames` package.

It is worth noting that the `!` is a part of the function name. [It's a Julia convention](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.6/manual/style-guide/#Append-!-to-names-of-functions-that-modify-their-arguments-1) to indicate that the function will mutate its argument.

Comment: It might be worth quickly explaining what the arguments are for in the function call and highlighting the `!` convention. That would make your answer a lot more valuable to newcomers.

Comment: @niczky12 thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my answer according to that.

Comment: It is `insertcols!` now, e.g. : `insertcols!(df, 3, :area => [1, 2] )`

Answer (score 5):

```
rows = size(df)[1]    # tuple gives you (rows,columns) of the DataFrame

insertcols!(df,       # DataFrame to be changed
    1,                # insert as column 1
    :Day => 1:rows,   # populate as "Day" with 1,2,3,..
    makeunique=true)  # if the name of the column exist, make is Day_1
```

Answer (score 0):

While making the question I also found a solution (as often happens).
I still post the question here for keep it in memory (for myself) and for the others..

It is enough to save the column names before "adding" the new column:

```
df = DataFrame(
  colour = ["green","blue"],
  shape = ["circle", "triangle"],
  border = ["dotted", "line"]
)
dfnames = names(df)
df[:area] = [1,2]

df = df[vcat(dfnames[1:1],:area,dfnames[2:end])]
```